# Apache Beam - Debug garbage collection to avoid OOM issues

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a very "standard" pipeline that performs windowed counts on what is now a bounded file-based collection but will, eventually, be an unbounded collection of events (e.g. a Kafka topic). The meat of the pipeline is below:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=my_options) as p:

    quote_counts = (
        p
        | "ReadQuotes" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(my_options.input_file)
        | "ConvertQuotes" >> beam.Map(convert_quote)
        | "AddQuoteTimestamps" >> beam.Map(add_quote_timestamp)
        | "WindowPerSecond" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.transforms.window.FixedWindows(1),
                                               trigger=beam.transforms.trigger.AfterWatermark(),
                                               accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
        | "AddKey" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem.instrument, 1))
        | "Count" >> beam.combiners.Count().PerKey()
        | "GetTimestamp" >> beam.Map(get_timestamp)
        | "Format" >> beam.Map(lambda t: "|".join(map(str, t)))
        | "WriteQuotes" >> beam.io.WriteToText(my_options.output_file)
    )
```

When I run it on a smallish (10k records, 660kB file) sample file, it produces the output I want: counts of events by second, keyed by instrument. When I run the pipeline on a larger sample (~29 million records, 1.9GB ... roughly 1 year of data), however, the pipeline process memory eventually jumps to 10GB+ and eventually is killed by the Linux OS.

Is there anything I'm doing in the pipeline above that would obviously cause such an explosion in memory? Is there a way to "force" garbage collection given the input source is largely sorted?

**What have I tried?**

1. I've tried changing the `trigger` from `DefaultTrigger` (which in theory is closer to what I want eventually) to `AfterWatermark`, to ensure the trigger only fires once.
2. I've tried changing the `accumulation_mode` to `DISCARDING`, even though `ACCUMULATING` may be more of what I want.
3. I've tried running what I think is a batch version of the above (using the Apache Beam's gamer score example as a template) ... which runs into the same memory problem.

   ```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=my_options) as p: 
    quote_counts = (
        p
        | "ReadQuotes" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(my_options.input_file)
        | "ConvertQuotes" >> beam.Map(convert_quote)
        | "AddQuoteTimestamps" >> beam.Map(add_quote_timestamp)
        | "WindowPerSecond" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.transforms.window.FixedWindows(1))
        | "AddKey" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem.instrument, 1))
        | "Count" >> beam.combiners.Count().PerKey()
        | "GetTimestamp" >> beam.Map(get_timestamp)
        | "Format" >> beam.Map(lambda t: "|".join(map(str, t)))
        | "WriteQuotes" >> beam.io.WriteToText(my_options.output_file)
    )
   ```
4. As this is really just for prototyping, I'm using the direct runner (i.e. not using Flink, Spark, etc.).

Comment: The direct runner is mainly for development work / functional testing. You should try the larger file with one of the production runners.

One other area you may want to look at , the WriteToText I think will make use of the window that you have in place. Which I think in this case may result in 1 file per sec per key.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The WriteToText only wrote one text file for the sample file, which had ~4,400 unique key/windows. So hopefully it'll just do one.

Comment: Quick update: FlinkRunner (1.10.2) ran the smaller file fine (sharding into 5 files, each 1000 windows, as you expected), but 1 of the 13 tasks failed on the larger file, failing the job. Will debug the FlinkRunner larger version and let you know.

Comment: If you want to collapse the files being generated, re-window into a larger window just before the WriteToText.